# matlab distance between two site: Why is the euclidean distance of two same point 9?

Tags: matlab, distance, euclidean-distance

This is code: The results are that a is 9 and b is 0. I'd like to know why is a 9.

```
txlat=0;
txlon=1;
rxlat=0;
rxlon=1;


tx=txsite('Latitude',txlat,"Longitude",txlon);
rx=rxsite('Latitude',rxlat,'Longitude',rxlon);

a=distance(tx,rx,'euclidean')
b=distance(tx,rx,'geodesic')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default [`AntennaHeight`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/antenna/ref/txsite.html#d117e49669) for `txsite` is 10 while the default `AntennaHeight` for `rxsite` is 1.

Nice catch.

---

EDIT:

If geodesic distance is what you want, you do not need to specify `AntennaHeight`. See below.

```
>> tx=txsite('Latitude',0,'Longitude',0.0001);
>> rx=rxsite('Latitude',0,'Longitude',0);
>> distance(tx,rx,'geodesic')
ans =
   11.1319


>> tx=txsite('Latitude',0,'Longitude',0.0001,'AntennaHeight',1);
>> rx=rxsite('Latitude',0,'Longitude',0);
>> distance(tx,rx,'geodesic')
ans =
   11.1319
```